# is it possible to find class name given class variable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```py
class A:
    var = 'hello'


type(A.var)               # returns: <class 'str'>
A.var.__class__.__name__  # returns: 'str'
vars(A)                   # returns: mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'var': 'hello', '__dict__': <attribute ' __dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>})
```

given `A.var` is it possible to find class A, or just var is related to class A, may be something similar to '**qualname**' for methods.

## Edited

reason I wanted to find the class name is I am implementing micro ORM, similar to SQLAlchemy using [declarative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#orm-declarative-mapping).

As you can see in this example.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

meta = sa.MetaData()
DeclarativeBase = sa.ext.declarative.declarative_base(metadata=meta)


class User(DeclartiveBase):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id            = sa.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = sa.Column(String)
    fullname      = sa.Column(String)
```

as you can see class is used as the abstraction for the real table, intresting thing is you can still access all the column using `vars(Users)` and filter column using `isinstance(<var>, sa.Column)`.

while doing query some how query is able to know which table the row is from, which is similar to the question I asked above, may its something to do with sa.Column.

```py
Session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

rows = session.query(
    User.id,
    User.name,
).all()
```

## Sample

This is sample of the implemenation, which is able to do basic table creating, insertion and update.

```py
class Col(str):
    pass

class Base:
    @classmethod
    def childs(cls):
        subclasses = set()
        work = [cls]
        while work:
            parent = work.pop()
            for child in parent.__subclasses__():
                if child not in subclasses:
                    subclasses.add(child)
                    work.append(child)
        return subclasses


    @classmethod
    def create(cls, cursor):
        query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({})'.format(
            cls.__tablename__,
            ', '.join(
                k + ' ' + v
                for k, v in vars(cls).items()
                if isinstance(v, Col)
            )
        )
        cursor.execute(query)


    @staticmethod
    def create_all_tables(cursor):
        for cls in __class__.childs():
            cls.create(cursor)


    @classmethod
    def drop(cls, cursor):
        query = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}'.format(
            cls.__tablename__,
        )
        cursor.execute(query)


    @classmethod
    def insert(cls, cursor, kvRow):
        query = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES(:{})'.format(
            cls.__tablename__,
            ', '.join(kvRow.keys()),
            ', :'.join(kvRow.keys())
        )
        cursor.execute(query, kvRow)
```

using it

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id            = Col('INTEGER PRIMARY KEY')
    name          = Col('VARCHAR')
    fullname      = Col('VARCHAR')
```

now creating table is similar to **sqlalchemy**     `meta.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)`

```py
import sqlite3

conn   = sqlite3.connect('./sqlite.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
Base.create_all_tables(cursor)
```

Which I don't understand is how sqlchemy `session.query` is able to understand the table the row is from.

Comment: `A.var` is just a name for your string `'hello'`, and the string knows nothing about the name(s) it's been given. What would your real use case for such a thing be?

Comment: What you want to do is not possible.  `A.var` has the value `'hello'`.  You can't find the name of your class from the string `'hello'`.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: No, there is nothing about the object `'hello'`'s data that can in any way be used to determine that the `A` class uses the attribute name `var` for it. Just like how your own name isn't encoded in your DNA.

Comment: Also, "class variable" is ambiguous and not proper terminology. You could mean: an *attribute* of the class (as you do here), a class *instance* (the result of `A()`), or possibly other things.

Comment: You could use either locals() or globals() (as appropriate) and identify classes that contain an attribute called (for example) *var*. However, the output would be ambiguous if you had more than one class with an attribute that happened to be called *var*

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm trying to understand how sqlachemy declarative mapping works for reimplementetion.

Comment: @kaya3 yes its was XY problem but no more i have added the explanation.

Comment: In your example, `User.name` is not a str, but a `sa.Column(String)` instance that certainly has an attribute referencing the `User` class. Just guessing here, but it's probably set when creating `User` by the metaclass of `DeclarativeBase`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes I know given example  ts string, but if `sa.Column` is instance how its doing it, I tried looking into the sqlalchemy source but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the main problem you deal with is: *How to make an object, when it is placed in the definition of a class as its attribute, "know" what class it belongs to?*

To achieve that, SQLAlchemy uses *metaclasses* (an advanced topic...), but there are simpler techniques, especially in modern versions of Python. One of them, which I think can be particularly handy for you, is to make your `Col` class implement a specific part of the *descriptor protocol*.

### A simple approach - `__set_name__`-based

Referring to the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), when it comes to your use case, the relevant part of the *descriptor protocol* is the method:

> `__set_name__(self, owner, name)`
>
> Called at the time the owning class **owner** is created. The descriptor has been assigned to **name**.

For example, you can implement this method as follows:

```
class Col(str):

    owner = None
    name = None

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.owner = owner
        self.name = name
```

Then, if you place in a class definition some instances of `Col` as attributes of that class, they will be notified about that, by invocation of their `__set_name__`, just after creation of the class. Thanks to that, each of them will "know" that class and the name obtained as an attribute of that class:

```
>>> class ArbitraryClass:
...     id            = Col('INTEGER PRIMARY KEY')
...     name          = Col('VARCHAR')
...     fullname      = Col('VARCHAR')
... 
>>> ArbitraryClass.id
'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
>>> ArbitraryClass.id.owner
<class '__main__.ArbitraryClass'>
>>> ArbitraryClass.id.name
'id'
>>> ArbitraryClass.name.owner
<class '__main__.ArbitraryClass'>
>>> ArbitraryClass.name.name
'name'
>>> ArbitraryClass.fullname.owner
<class '__main__.ArbitraryClass'>
>>> ArbitraryClass.fullname.name
'fullname'
```

### An alternative approach - `__init_subclass__`-based

```
# We keep `Col` very simple:
class Col(str):
    owner = None
    name = None

# ...as the responsibility of detecting `Col` attributes
# is taken by the `Base` class:
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
            if isinstance(obj, Col):
                obj.owner = cls
                obj.name = name
    # And below the rest of your implementation of `Base`...
```

See the [docs of `__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__).

Example use of the above definitions:

```
>>> class Table(Base):
...     id            = Col('INTEGER PRIMARY KEY')
...     name          = Col('VARCHAR')
...     fullname      = Col('VARCHAR')
... 
>>> Table.id
'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'
>>> Table.id.owner
<class '__main__.Table'>
>>> Table.id.name
'id'
>>> Table.name.owner
<class '__main__.Table'>
>>> Table.name.name
'name'
>>> Table.fullname.owner
<class '__main__.Table'>
>>> Table.fullname.name
'fullname'
```

### Another alternative approach - *metaclass*-based

Yet another possibility is to use a [*metaclass*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) -- in a way which is quite similar to what we have done above with `__init_subclass__`.

```
# Again, we keep `Col` very simple:
class Col(str):
    owner = None
    name = None

# ...because a metaclass will do the work:
class BaseMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
            if isinstance(obj, Col):
                obj.owner = cls
                obj.name = name
        return cls

class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
    # Note: ↑ by passing `metaclass=BaseMeta` we say:
    # the class of the `Base` class is `BaseMeta`.
    # That's the essence: *metaclass* == *class of a class*.

    # And below the rest of your implementation of `Base`...
```

Usage is the same as in the case of the `__init_subclass__()`-based approach...

Note: metaclasses are a very powerful tool, as you can customize with them various stages of the class creation process. Here, however, I believe engaging them would be overkill. Moreover, using this technique becomes troublesome when you need capabilities provided by more than one metaclass. Composing different existing metaclasses may turn out to be difficult or even impossible.

So I'd rather suggest one of the simpler approaches described earlier.

Comment: Is the `Col` class (in the first part _"descriptor based"_) really a descriptor? It does not match the definition (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction), because none of the 3 special methods of the descriptor protocol is defined. The `__set_name__` hook is described in description protocol docs, OTOH the related PEP (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) says _"The second part of the proposal adds an `__set_name__` initializer for class attributes, especially if they are descriptors."_. Isn't the `Col` just a class attribute, but not a descriptor?

Comment: @VPfB Good point. Although the terminology seems to be vague here... Strictly speaking, you are right: `Col` is not a descriptor, as it does not provide `__get__` or `__set__`, or `__delete__`. On the other hand `__set_name__` is documented as a part of the *descriptor* protocol...

Comment: PS To avoid confusion, I reworded the fragments referring to the *descriptors* and *descriptor protocol*. Thanks, @VPfB, for your remark.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It looks like we both agree that the documentation is a bit vague in this point.

Comment: good news, the  `__set_name__` documentation will be updated. It is called for all attributes that define this method, not only descriptors. (bpo-45198)

Answer (score 1):

If you want find the model class that a column in the query "belongs" to, you can use the query's [column_descriptions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.column_descriptions) attribute:

```py
q = session.query(User.id, User.name)
q.column_descriptions
```

outputs

```
[{
     'name': 'id',
     'type': Integer(),
     'aliased': False,
     'expr': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fa18b87dcc0>,
     'entity': <class '__main__.User'>
 }, 
 {
     'name': 'name',
     'type': String(),
     'aliased': False,
     'expr': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fa18b87dd60>,
     'entity': <class '__main__.User'>
}]
```

so the model class can be found in the value of the `entity` key for each column.  This works for both the 1.x `session.query` syntax and the 2.0 `sa.select(User.id, User.name)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not possible to associate the class A, to the variable, because you are creating a class A, but instatiating a String that has nothing to do with that class.
If you create the class, and associate an attribute, instead of just creating a raw string inside the class, than you can return the class.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__value == other
    def retunclass(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

var = A('hello')             #var = 'hello'
print(var.retunclass())      #>>> 'A'

if var == 'hello':
    print(True)              #>>> True
```